# Error 'Invalid Column Name' while the column name exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLES') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TABLES
SELECT  TABLE_NAME,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RNUM into #Tables  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE COLUMN_NAME Like '%Client_ID%' Or COLUMN_NAME Like '%ClientID%' AND
TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'CR%' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'Z%' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%_CHANGE'
AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'VW%'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#finaldata') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #finaldata
CREATE TABLE #finaldata(table_name VARCHAR(100),noofrows INT,Last_modified DATETIME)


DECLARE @start INT=1,@end INT,@tablename VARCHAR(100),@Client_ID     INT=1124,@query VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @end=MAX(RNUM) FROM #Tables 
WHILE @start<=@end
BEGIN
SELECT @tablename=TABLE_NAME FROM #Tables WHERE RNUM=@start

SELECT @query=CONCAT('INSERT INTO #finaldata(table_name,noofrows)
SELECT ','''',@tablename,'''',' ,COUNT(1) FROM ',@tablename ,'     WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE Client_id=',@Client_ID)

EXEC(@query)
SELECT @start=@start+1
END

select * from #finaldata where noofrows>0

--select * from FORM_DETAIL where Client_id = -1
```

result was like

> 1 row affected 
>    1 row affected 
>    error 207 , level 16 , invalid column_name client_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HoneyBadger correctly commented, you are searching for more than one column name, but have hardcoded a single column name into your dynamic SQL.

You can correct this as follows by storing the column name along with the table name and then using it in the dynamic SQL:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLES') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #TABLES;
END

-- I assume you want brackets as I have shown below to ensure the 'and-ed' conditions apply to both 'or-ed' conditions    
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RNUM
into #Tables
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE (COLUMN_NAME Like '%Client_ID%' Or COLUMN_NAME Like '%ClientID%')
AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'CR%' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'Z%' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%_CHANGE'
AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'VW%';

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#finaldata') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #finaldata;
END

CREATE TABLE #finaldata(table_name VARCHAR(100), noofrows INT, Last_modified DATETIME);

DECLARE @start INT=1, @end INT, @tablename VARCHAR(100), @columnname VARCHAR(100), @Client_ID INT=1124, @query VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @end = MAX(RNUM)
FROM #Tables;

WHILE @start <= @end BEGIN
  SELECT @tablename=TABLE_NAME, @columnname = COLUMN_NAME FROM #Tables WHERE RNUM = @start;

  SELECT @query = CONCAT('INSERT INTO #finaldata(table_name, noofrows)
    SELECT ','''',@tablename,'''',', COUNT(1) FROM ', @tablename, ' WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ' + @columnname + ' = ', @Client_ID);

  print(@Query)
  --EXEC(@query);
  SELECT @start=@start+1;
END

select * from #finaldata where noofrows>0
```